# Get drag&drop position

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-dragula

I use angular-js dragula for drag&drop

I need to save position, because user choose custom div position.
This is how my html look

```
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='container' dragula='"first-bag"'>
    <div>You can move these elements between these two containers</div>
    <div>Moving them anywhere else isn't quite possible</div>
    <div>There's also the possibility of moving elements around in the same container, changing their position</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

With `$scope.$on` I get `over` and `out` event, but I can't get `id` or something similar for get position, to store in cookie.

```
$scope.$on('first-bag.over', function (e, el) {
  el.addClass('over');
  console.log(e);
  console.log(el);
})

$scope.$on('first-bag.out', function (e, el) {
  el.removeClass('over');
  console.log(e);
  console.log(el);
});
```

Here is plunker, open console to see what happens.
Pls, if someone knows how to on every drag&drop save div order, soo next time when user come back to get saved position. Thnx

https://plnkr.co/edit/AeGw9A3196DsYBHFv98b?p=preview